# There are 9 white balls and 4 red balls . How many different ways are there to select a subset of 6 balls, assuming the 13 balls are different?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are 9 white balls and 4 red balls in an urn. How many different ways are there to select a subset of 6 balls, assuming the 13 balls are different?
What is the fraction of selections with 4 whites and 2 reds?

I not sure the first part of question, I get C(13,6)/(9!4!), is this right?

Comment: If the balls are different, why divide by (9!4!) ?

Comment: You are overthinking the first question. Just forget about the colors and consider them all different. And avoid asking 3 questions per post.

Answer (score 1):

Since the balls are distinct, the number of subsets of $6$ of the $13$ balls is simply $$\binom{13}{6}$$

For the second part of the question, divide the number of ways of selecting $4$ of the $9$ white balls and $2$ of the $4$ red balls by the answer to the first question.

Comment: Thanks for your help